# CSS selector for parent with blank element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a selector for all `<li>` elements containing a blank `<p>` element:

```css
li>p:blank {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <p>Size</p>
  <p></p> <!-- blank -->
</li>

<li>
  <p>Color</p>
  <p>Blue</p> <!-- NOT blank -->
</li>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  However- the pseudo class is `:empty` not `:blank`:

```css
li>p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <p>Size</p>
  <p></p> <!-- blank -->
</li>

<li>
  <p>Color</p>
  <p>Blue</p> <!-- NOT blank -->
</li>
```

Comment: Pretty much what I needed, just that I wanted to select the `<li>` (the parent) rather than the `<p>` so that I can hide the `<li>` completely including the children `<p>` elements

Comment: @Dan I don't believe that is possible, as you cannot select parent elements based on child elements.  You would need Javascript.

Comment: I was able to achieve this using a data selector, e.g. `<li data="{COLOR}"> 
 <p>Color</p> <p>{COLOR}</p> </li>` where `{COLOR}` renders plain text into the HTML. CSS: `[data=''] {display:none; }`